# Is there any way to determine if a time input is partial filled or empty?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've an `<input type="time">`. Chrome allows the user to partially fill out the input. E.g. user enters hours but no minutes or the other way around. Is there any way using JavaScript to check if that element is empty or is partly filled out?

The `value` property is empty as long as the input is only filled partly. So that one doesn't work. Is there any property that could be used?

Actually I'm not interested on the partly entered value. Just want to improve user experience by warning that a time without hour or minute is not valid and will be ignored.

JSBin https://jsbin.com/pikabowoyo/edit?html,js,output

```js
let el = document.querySelector('button');
el.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let input = document.querySelector('input');
  console.log(input.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="time">
<button>show value</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The time input is invalid if partially filled. If you leave the input empty, and click the button, you'll get an empty value. If you'll half fill the input, and click the button, the input would be marked as invalid.

```js
const el = document.querySelector('button');
el.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const input = document.querySelector('input');
  
  const validity = input.checkValidity();
  
  console.log(validity ? input.value : 'partial');
});
```

```css
.time:invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="time" class="time">
<button>show value</button>
```

Comment: This does not work in Firefox. Seems like Firefox does not consider a partially filled input as invalid. It's not an issue in Edge as that UI prevents user from partially filling a time input. Desktop Safari and IE11 does not even support input type time. Haven't tested Safari on iOS. But support for Firefox would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

That is alas not possible. The field does not have a value until completed.

I could not find where it says the client MUST fill in a complete time before it can be interrogated

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#time-state-(type%3Dtime)

If this is for validation purposes, you can use required and the user will not be allowed to have a partial input

If you do not want to make it required, to test for validity you can use [reportValidity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) or

`HTMLFormElement.checkValidity()`

> Returns true if the element's child controls are subject to constraint validation and satisfy those contraints; returns false if some controls do not satisfy their constraints. Fires an event named invalid at any control that does not satisfy its constraints; such controls are considered invalid if the event is not canceled. It is up to the programmer to decide how to respond to false.

Comment: It's for validation purposes but the field should be optional. So using `required` attribute is not an option. The validation should warn the user that entering `13:--` is not a shortcut for `13:00` but the same as `--:--`. I hoped that there is a fancy way using a CSS pseudo selector, event listeners for `keypress` / `click` or some other hacky solution.